# lmer reference output interpretation

Tags: r, lm, lme4

I need confirmation that I am correctly interpreting the output of my summary(lmer model)
I have 5 continuous covariates (AGE, BMI, GDS, POLYPH, EDU) and 3 categorical covariates (SEX, TIME, APOE4) and the interaction of interest (GAIT:TIME; GAIT: 2 levels, TIME: 4 levels)

TIME: bl, m12, m24, m36

GAIT: normal, abnormal

```
fit = lmer(test ~ GAIT:TIME+
            TIME+
            APOE4+
            AGE+
            GDS+
            POLYPH.+
            EDU+
            SEX+
            BMI+
            (1|SITE:ID), 
            control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")
                  data  = df)  

summary(fit)
```

I understand that the reference of TIME is TIME[bl], so the estimates of m12, m24, m36 are compared to bl.
Instead, the reference for each interaction estimate is the following?

- GAIT_abnormal:TIME[bl] vs. GAIT_normal:TIME[bl]
- GAIT_abnormal:TIME[12] vs. GAIT_normal:TIME[12]
- GAIT_abnormal:TIME[24] vs. GAIT_normal:TIME[24]
- GAIT_abnormal:TIME[36] vs. GAIT_normal:TIME[36]

So I get how the estimates vary for each time point between the two levels of GAIT?

THANKS!

[image]

Comment: The model does not account for the ordering of interval scaled time. I would model TIME in numbers of  0,12,24 and 36. Otherwise, you do not model progression over time.

Comment: Thanks! Ok so I get this output estimate `GAIT_abnormal:TIME  -0.018623   0.008809 682.032893  -2.114  0.03486 * ` that is GAIT_abnormal by time, compared to GAIT_normal by time?

Comment: There is a significant influence of time on GAIT when it comes to predict the test outcome. Meaning influence of GAIT changes over time so there must be something else as well responsible to different test outcomes. Why is GAIT itself not included in the model? Usually, one write GAIT*TIME here.

Comment: GAIT is taken only at TIME 0 and it is not a covariate as I have predictions that patterns of gait at T0 could affect the outcome test at different time points and so I did not want to adjust the estimate by something I am looking for. Do you think is more correct to account also for the main effect of GAIT? I do not understand what do you mean by "there must be something else as well responsible to different test outcomes"

Comment: If GAIT was only taken at one time point, it does not make any sense to include GAIT:time. You can not measure progression or dynamic impact on time if you only have one time point. Then just include only the main effect of GAIT w/o time interactions. Time is a proxy for everything you have not measured. Look at any equation in physics: They do not have time itself in their equation. Science must be reproducible thus be independent on time. If interaction terms like GAIT:time are significant, GAIT alone is not sufficient to predict test outcome, you also need time here.But GAIT:time is invalid

Comment: Can you please include your summary table as text (in a code block) rather than as an image?